# Declaring Class conforming to protocol in Swift

Tags: swift

In objective-C we can declare a Class that conforms to some protocol as

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Class<UIObjectRestoration> objectRestorationClass;
```

and can assign value to it as

```
someObject.objectRestorationClass = [SomeClass class];
```

Question is:
How can i do it in Swift ? I tried using

```
var objectRestorationClass: UIObjectRestoration!
```

and

```
someObject.objectRestorationClass = SomeClass.self
```

but its giving me the error

> 'SomeClass.Type' does not convert to protocol 'UIObjectRestoration'

SomeClass is :

```
class SomeClass: UIViewController, UIObjectRestoration {

 class func objectWithRestorationIdentifierPath(identifierComponents: [AnyObject]!, coder: NSCoder!) -> UIStateRestoring! {

        return restoringObject
    }

}
```

I tried by typecasting it but its giving me same error .

Comment: Is there any noticeable difference between using `Class<UIObjectRestoration>` and just `Class` in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var objectRestorationClass: UIObjectRestoration.Type!
```

Answer (score 0):

`[UIObjectRestoration]` is an array of UIObjectRestoration items. Use 
`var objectRestorationClass : UIObjectRestoration` and assign value with `objectRestorationClass = SomeClass.classForCoder`

Comment: 'AnyClass' not identical to 'UIObjectRestoration'